# Draw horizontal rule in React Native

Tags: react-native

I've tried [react-native-hr](https://github.com/Riglerr/react-native-hr) package - doesn't work for me nor on Android nor on iOS.

Following code is also not suitable because it renders three dots at the end

```
<Text numberOfLines={1}}>               
    ______________________________________________________________
</Text>
```

Comment: <Text>__________ Level {level} __________</Text>

Answer (score 470, accepted):

You could simply use an empty View with a bottom border.

```
<View
  style={{
    borderBottomColor: 'black',
    borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
  }}
/>
```

Comment: I recommend `borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth` :)

Comment: if it doesn't work consider adding alignSelf:'stretch'.

Comment: you should specify the WIDTH value for the view.

Comment: by this able to draw line but left and right there is a margin . I want to draw end to end

Comment: @Abhi That seems like an issue that is not related to this answer. Please create a new question if you do not find a solution

Comment: In some devices borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth will be not displayed at all (at least on RN 0.61)

Answer (score 113):

I was able to draw a separator with `flexbox` properties even with a text in the center of line.

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center'}}>
  <View style={{flex: 1, height: 1, backgroundColor: 'black'}} />
  <View>
    <Text style={{width: 50, textAlign: 'center'}}>Hello</Text>
  </View>
  <View style={{flex: 1, height: 1, backgroundColor: 'black'}} />
</View>
```

[image]

Comment: This is the best answer, it scales and if you don't set a Text width it will be dynamic

Comment: For the Text component, remove style width and add paddingHorizontal, otherwise text is format in a box of 50 pixels. `<Text style={{textAlign: 'center', paddingHorizontal:8}}>Hello Friends !</Text>`

Answer (score 30):

One can use margin in order to change the width of a line and place it center.

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native;
<View style = {styles.lineStyle} />

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  lineStyle:{
        borderWidth: 0.5,
        borderColor:'black',
        margin:10,
   }
 });
```

if you want to give margin dynamically then you can use Dimension width.

Comment: Thanks. You could also just `<View style = {styles.lineStyle} />` since nothing is in between ;-)

Comment: Smit `styles.lineStyle` would correspond to a `const styles = StyleSheet.create({ lineStyle: ... });` here. You just have `lineStyle = { ...}` which would cause an issue. A complete solution with `styles.lineStyle` could be `const styles = StyleSheet.create({ lineStyle: { borderWidth: 0.5, borderColor: 'black', margin: 10 } });`.

Comment: yeah. you're right. here I assume that you put `lineStyle` inside your StyleSheet.

Answer (score 14):

I recently had this problem.

```
<Text style={styles.textRegister}> ────────  Register With  ────────</Text>
```

with this result:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't scale well

Comment: as simple as that.

Comment: @PetrusTheron why does it not scale well?

Comment: @NateGlenn hyphens will wrap on a narrow display or appear too thin on a wider display.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I think the solution is fine if if you only need a very short line.

Comment: This is not recommended.

Comment: This doesn't take into account screen width

Answer (score 10):

I did it like this. Hope this helps

```
<View style={styles.hairline} />
<Text style={styles.loginButtonBelowText1}>OR</Text>
<View style={styles.hairline} />
```

for style:

```
hairline: {
  backgroundColor: '#A2A2A2',
  height: 2,
  width: 165
},

loginButtonBelowText1: {
  fontFamily: 'AvenirNext-Bold',
  fontSize: 14,
  paddingHorizontal: 5,
  alignSelf: 'center',
  color: '#A2A2A2'
},
```

Comment: I think it's the best solution. Better than using border like other answers.

Comment: Hardcoding width might be a bit of a problem.

Answer (score 8):

Creating a reusable `Line` component worked for me:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';

export default function Line() {
    return (
        <View style={{
            height: 1,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255 ,0.3)',
            alignSelf: 'stretch'
        }} />
    )
}
```

Now, Import and use `Line` anywhere:

```js
<Line />
```

Comment: `alignSelf: 'stretch'` is the key in this answer, thank you very much.

Answer (score 7):

You can also try `react-native-hr-component`

```
npm i react-native-hr-component --save
```

Your code:

```
import Hr from 'react-native-hr-component'

//..

<Hr text="Some Text" fontSize={5} lineColor="#eee" textPadding={5} textStyles={yourCustomStyles} hrStyles={yourCustomHRStyles} />
```

Comment: That's a bit of a overkill

Answer (score 6):

This is in React Native (JSX) code, updated to today:

```
<View style = {styles.viewStyleForLine}></View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
viewStyleForLine: {
    borderBottomColor: "black", 
    borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth, 
    alignSelf:'stretch',
    width: "100%"
  }
})
```

you can use either `alignSelf:'stretch'` or `width: "100%"` both should work...
and,

```
borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth
```

here `StyleSheet.hairlineWidth` is the thinnest, 
then,

```
borderBottomWidth: 1,
```

and so on to increase thickness of the line.

Answer (score 3):

```
import { View, Dimensions } from 'react-native'

var { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window')

// Create Component

<View style={{
   borderBottomColor: 'black', 
   borderBottomWidth: 0.5, 
   width: width - 20,}}>
</View>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use native element divider.

Install it with:

```
npm install --save react-native-elements
# or with yarn
yarn add react-native-elements

import { Divider } from 'react-native-elements'
```

Then go with:

```
<Divider style={{ backgroundColor: 'blue' }} />
```

[Source](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/getting_started.html)

Comment: Installing a whole package (and likely a big one) seems like overkill if you only need a horizontal line.

Comment: Granted it is overkill if you will only be using the `<Divider /> ` component, however, you should be using a library either way to save time in styling simple buttons, Search Bars etc... etc... 

Checkout all that it could do for your app
https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/

Answer (score 2):

just add the following code to get your desired result :
`<View style={{ borderBottomColor: 'black', borderBottomWidth: 1, }} />`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do something like this?

```
<View
  style={{
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: 'black',
    width: 400,
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this with native base package

```
<Flex alignItems='center' justifyContent='center' direction='row'>
   <Divider width={150} mx="5" />
   <Text>OR</Text>
   <Divider width={150} mx="5" />
</Flex>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import {Dimensions} from 'react-native'

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window')

<View
  style={{
         borderBottomColor: '#1D3E5E',
         borderBottomWidth: 1,
         width : width , 
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i solved divider with horizontal lines and text in the midddle:

```
<View style={styles.divider}>
  <View style={styles.hrLine} />
  <Text style={styles.dividerText}>OR</Text>
  <View style={styles.hrLine} />
</View>
```

And styles for this:

```
import { Dimensions, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'

const { width } = Dimensions.get('window')

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
divider: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: 10,
  },
  hrLine: {
    width: width / 3.5,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    height: 1,
  },
  dividerText: {
    color: 'white',
    textAlign: 'center',
    width: width / 8,
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a View component which has small height.

```
<View style={{backgroundColor:'black', height:10}}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a solid background (like white), this could be your solution:

```
<View style={container}>
  <View style={styles.hr} />
  <Text style={styles.or}>or</Text>
</View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 0,
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    width: '100%',
  },
  hr: {
    position: 'relative',
    top: 11,
    borderBottomColor: '#000000',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
  },
  or: {
    width: 30,
    fontSize: 14,
    textAlign: 'center',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { Divider, Text } from 'react-native-paper';

const MyComponent = () => (
  <View>
    <Text>Lemon</Text>
    <Divider />
    <Text>Mango</Text>
    <Divider />
  </View>
);

export default MyComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the View like this to render a horizontal rule:

```
<View style={{ backgroundColor : "your color", height : 1 }} />
```

Comment: There's a typo (on backgroud). It should be `<View style={{ backgroundColor: "your color", height: 1 }} />`

Comment: @ghashi it's not a typo it's just a space, i like giving spaces around colons

Comment: "backgroudColor" is missing an "n", therefore it should be "backgroundColor", (not "backgroudColor")

Answer (score 0):

I use this component. It has two props: 1. Number of dash need. 2. dashWidth. and use it like this:

```
<Line dashedCount={Math.floor(screenWidth / 12)} dashWidth={8} />
```

```
type TLine = {
    dashedCount: number;
    dashWidth: number;
};

function Line({ dashedCount, dashWidth }: TLine) {
    const Dash = ({ dashWidth }) => (
        <View
            style={{
                height: 1,
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255 ,0.3)',
                alignSelf: 'stretch',
                width: dashWidth
            }}
        />
    );
    const dashed = Array(dashedCount).fill(<Dash dashWidth={dashWidth} />);

    return (
        <View
            style={{
                flexDirection: 'row',
                justifyContent: 'space-between'
            }}
        >
            {dashed}
        </View>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For horizontal line in React native`<Text style={{ height:1,width:"100%",backgroundColor:"black",margin:5}}></Text>`

Answer (score 0):

Use an empty View and give it CSS styles,
In the View, put an empty Text for the view not to be ignored as seen in the snippet below

```
<View style={{ height: 1, width: "100%",backgroundColor: "black",}}><Text></Text></View>
```

Answer (score 0):

<Text style={{borderColor:"gray",borderWidth:0.3,height:1, marginTop: 10}} />

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should try using react-native-hr something like this:

```
<Hr lineColor='#b3b3b3'/>
```

documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-hr

Comment: looking issues on the repo, it doesn't seem so "active" and up-to-date in term of dependencies :(

Answer (score -1):

Just paste this code in **View** it will work perfectly.

```
Line: {
    borderBottomColor: "black",
    borderBottomWidth: 1
}
```