# Create an horizontal separator

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to create an horizontal line(separator) with react native. The separator should have a left and right space. I tried to use this code found on the site

```
<View
  style={{
    borderBottomColor: 'black',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    left: 5,
    right:5
  }}
/>
```

The problem is that the right padding is not working. Also the line looks bad, is there any way to make a small shadow? Or is there a component that enables to create separators?

Comment: Small shadow? You want to create `elevation` for your Views?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Draw horizontal rule in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43380260/draw-horizontal-rule-in-react-native)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`left` and `right` props are for positioning the component/element. You should use `marginRight` and `marginLeft` props to get desired effect.

**Example**

```
<View
  style={{
    borderBottomColor: 'black',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    marginLeft: 5,
    marginRight: 5
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Or `marginHorizontal: 5`

Answer (score 0):

you can use flexbox to draw this (was read this from [Draw horizontal rule in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43380260/draw-horizontal-rule-in-react-native) - Azhar Zafar's answer)

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center'}}>
  <View style={{flex: 1, height: 1, backgroundColor: 'black'}} />
  <View>
    <Text style={{width: 50, textAlign: 'center'}}>Hello</Text>
  </View>
  <View style={{flex: 1, height: 1, backgroundColor: 'black'}} />
</View>
```