# React Native: borderBottom does not show up in empty View

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

In my React Native app, I try to create a simple divider line. As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43380260/draw-horizontal-rule-in-react-native) for example, I created an empty View and added the corresponding styling to it.

Now here's the thing: the divider line is not showing up with this code:

```
    <View style={styles.divider}>
      <Text></Text>
    </View>

... Stylesheet:

  divider: {
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderLeftColor: 'white',
  },
```

[image]

But If I add some text lines, it shows up:

```
    <View style={styles.divider}>
      <Text>testtest</Text>
    </View>

... Stylesheet:

  divider: {
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderLeftColor: 'white',
  },
```

[image]

Now here is the code context.

```
   <View style={styles.containerWholePage}>
      <View style={styles.containerUpper}>
        <Text style={styles.mainText}>Here is a sample text</Text>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.containerLower}>
        <View style={styles.containerText}>
          <Text>TEST</Text>
          <Text>Example 3</Text>
          <Text>18:00 - 20:00</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.divider}>
          <Text>testtest</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.containerText}>
          <Text>TEST2</Text>
          <Text>Example 3b</Text>
          <Text>18:00 - 19:00</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
```

...

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  containerWholePage: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    flex: 1,
  },
  divider: {
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: 'white',
  },
  containerLower: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    backgroundColor: '#1E2928',
    flex: 6,
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
  },
  containerText: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#1E2928',
  },
  containerUpper: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    flex: 3,
  },
});
```

Maybe you have an idea how to make the bottom line appear without having to write text?

Comment: Add some `height` to your `view` with className divider

Comment: @arnavpanwar99 Does not work >.<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do like this:

```js
<View style={styles.divider}/>
...
divider: {
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: 'white',
    width:"100%"
},
```

Because the width is flexible to it's content, so if nothing in it, it doesn't have width. So that if you set the width, the `View` will have width setting as you want.

[Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-bush-ujq53)
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Basically that should work I just tested it in sandbox and adding a

```
<View style={{borderBottomWidth: 1}} >
<Text></Text>
</View>
```

worked perfect for me.. maybe add a {" "} between the Text tags.

Comment: It's seem doesn't work even I add {" "} between the Text tags ...It's shows a very little short line on sandbox...    https://codesandbox.io/s/white-sun-4w4yp

Comment: Yeah it is because of the way that the container is set up if u get rid of alignItems: "center" from containerLower style it works

Comment: I got it, because I change it by his code in first thought hope to let him fast to achieve. lol

Comment: yeah I just tried it in an empty sandbox thats why it worked for me :D

Answer (score 1):

you can also try:

```
    <View style={styles.divider}/>

    divider: {
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: 'white',
    alignSelf:"stretch"
    },
```

but I prefer just using width: "100%"