# How do I do a separator line with a dot in the middle on react native?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, frontend

I want to do a line like this one, but I don't know how (btw the text on the image is in spanish, but it does not matter).[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can draw a separator with `flexbox` properties even with a text or view or anything you want in the center of the line.

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center'}}>
  <View style={{flex: 1, height: 1, backgroundColor: 'black'}} />
  <View>
    <Text style={{textAlign: 'center', paddingHorizontal:8}}>Hello</Text>
  </View>
  <View style={{flex: 1, height: 1, backgroundColor: 'black'}} />
</View>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Pls, take a look at this link.
Hope it will help.
[Draw horizontal rule in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43380260/draw-horizontal-rule-in-react-native)
It can be done easily by installing packages.
https://daisyui.com/components/divider/

Answer (score 0):

It can be done easily without adding any library. Here's an exmaple -
https://snack.expo.dev/@arjunshukla97/divider